# How to fill 3D matrix with correlation values using a loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to do  spatial rainfall correlations between rainfall time series and the SST. My code is as follows

```
#'OND_rainfall_index_list' is a list of 27 (1990-2016) values of spatially averaged rainfall in eastern Africa
#trial_x is a (27,48,80) multidimensional array of SST (time, lat,lon) in the Indian Ocean 
corr = np.zeros((27,48,80))
corr.shape
for m in range(48):
    for n in range(80):
        corr[m,n]=stats.pearsonr(OND_rainfall_index_list, trial_x[:,m,n])[0]
```

`OND_rainfall_index_list` is a `list` of 27 values of spatially averaged rainfall in eastern Africa whereas `trial_x` is a multidimensional array of SST.

I am trying to initialize a matrix which I can then fill with correlation values. I would like to end up with a matrix of the same size as `trial_x` but with correlation values instead. How can I go about this? At the moment I get the following error when I run the loop.

```
> IndexError: index 48 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 48
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix `corr` has the shape `(27,48,80)`. Which is a 3D array.

However, you have the line:

```
corr[m,n]=stats.pearsonr(OND_rainfall_index_list, trial_x[:,m,n])[0]
```

What do you expect `corr[m, n]` to relate to? The 1st and 2nd dimension or the 2nd and 3rd?

I expect the 2nd and 3rd.

So, if the output of this:

```
stats.pearsonr(OND_rainfall_index_list, trial_x[:,m,n])[0]
```

has a size of `(27,)`, then use:

```
corr[:, m,n]=stats.pearsonr(OND_rainfall_index_list, trial_x[:,m,n])[0]
```

but if it has a size of `(1,)`, then use:

```
corr = np.zeros((48,80))
```